# Does 2sxc have tags and categories?

Tags: 2sxc

I've yet to find that 2sxc has facilities for entering, browsing, filtering and otherwise allowing keyword based filtering/sorting. If so, is there documentation about this, or sample code perhaps?

I'd think it might also be likely that one could use DNN's pretty good capabilities for tags and categories, and also razor queries would enable this, but I'd sure love to see some examples/guidance on best practices for doing so from within 2sxc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do, but it's much more advanced that just tags / categories.

Basically you

1. Create a new ContentType for the related information - like Tag, Category or whatever. It can have more fields than just a title, as a category could also have an icon
2. Add some of that data
3. Go to the content type where you want to use it, create a "Entity / Content-Item" field
4. Then go to the field settings, give it the name of the related info that is allawed and if 1 or more items may be added (category is often just 1, Tags is often many)

that's it :)

Comment: Oh perfect! I just came across that Entity item yesterday with  the Feedback's Category (Question/Complaint) item that's stored in a separate Content item (and App Resources). I'm still using just dropdowns as they suffice for now, but maybe for phase 2 I explore this more.   --- Delighted on the left coast of the US.

Comment: great. if this answers your question, you should mark the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a start on this at:
http://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/2685
and the demo at
http://2sxc.org/dnn-app-demos/en/Apps/FAQ-with-Categories

Comment: Ohhh, 8.3 just added a bunch of neat facities for this, as described at; http://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/8147